# Error message inside a loop - Pong game

Tags: loops, smallbasic

I am making a game similar to pong in small basic. What I want to do is when the ball hits the wall the game ends and shows an error message.

What I did was use a while loop as such below:

```
While (hits right wall) or (hits left wall) or (hits top wall) or (hits bottom wall) = "True" 
    GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage("you lost", "game over")
Endwhile
```

What that actually does is keep repeating the error message and I have to quit the program. How can I get it to just show the message once when the conditions for it hitting either wall is true?

Comment: Learn more about creating [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `break` once the condition is met and once you show the error message.

Comment: How do you break in SmallBasic program?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60cd4f4a-10d7-42a3-af35-206502abbc93/break-in-a-for-loop?forum=smallbasic

Comment: I have tried to do that. I did ==========>>>>

While loop (conditions) = "true"
endwhile
ShowMessage

But its not working. Still the same thing happens

Comment: Use `if` instead of while.

Comment: Same thing happens still.

Comment: Small Basic doesn't have a break command and using the Goto for logic this complex is never a good idea. You should create a flag variable and have a series of if statements that set the flag when you need to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a flag!

Before your loop you set a flag to true. Your loop is based on just that flag. Then for each exit condition that you need you have a separate if statement that handles that logic. When that condition is met, you set the flag to false.

This keeps the code simple, and the logic easy to follow.

Example:

```
gameOn = "true"

While gameOn = "true"
  'Code to control your game

  If (hitsLeftWall) Then
    gameOn = "false"
  ElseIf (hitsRightWall) then
    gameOn = "false"
  ElseIf (hitsLTopWall) then
    gameOn = "false"
  ElseIf (hitsBottomWall) then
    gameOn = "false"
  EndIf
EndWhile
```